# Make Raspberry Pi to work as AP and Station to receive wireless temperature sensor values

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, rpi.gpio, access-point, xbee

Hi after reading the manual of Xbee device, I am able to use XBee device with raspberry pi.

But how to make raspberry pi to work as an access point as well as the station at the same time?

using access point it will receive the data from mesh-based [wireless temperature sensor](https://store.ncd.io/product/industrial-iot-wireless-temperature-humidity-sensor/) through the gateway receiver connected with raspberry pi and at the same time, it will send the data to Azure IoT hub?

Any suggestion about where should I start will be a great help

Answer (score 1):

A Raspberry Pi with a built-in wifi device is able to work as access point and at the same time to connect to another remote access point as client. But the wifi driver has some quirks that make it a bit complicated to achieve this. For a solution with *systemd-networkd* you can look at [Access point as WiFi repeater, optional with bridge](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/89804/79866).